# jQuery random var on page refresh

Tags: jquery

I use some script that play attaches a bg youtube video, to a div ID.

However we have numerous vidoes, that I would like to display at random on page refresh. Obviously one each time, and in any order whatsoever. To better explain the code below, attaches the videoID to the youtube player for ID #wrapper

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var options = { videoId: 'pFhjQFF_Sgg', start: 3 };
$('#wrapper').tubular(options);
});
```

The youtube id is pFhjQFF_Sgg

I wish to add an array of video id's that would be selected randomly at each page refresh. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Javascript only or also Php?

Comment: Normally would prefer php not sure if dooable in this instance, demo url: http://oldcodgers.com.au/

Comment: Google Math.Random() to get random numbers from 0 to array.length

Comment: why would i use math random, clueless here as the id's are specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you can maintain an Array of the IDs, you can get random from the array

```
var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this in the end, thanks guys.

```
<?php
 $items = array("pFhjQFF_Sgg", "4cYdXqnt3Aw", "uvU0DjCPQa4");
?>
 $('document').ready(function() {
var options = { videoId: '<?php echo $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)];?>', start: 3    };
$('#wrapper').tubular(options);
 });
```